# Setting up the "load-more" functionality outside of the bootstrap widget (Laravel 4)

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-4

I currently have a "load-more" widget using jquery that displays more data from a database as you click the "more" button.  I have the data within the widget, but I would like to pull the data (and have the same functionality), outside of the widget.

Right now, this is the javascript and HTML I have:

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

<?php $number_of_posts = 2; ?>;
<?php $_SESSION['posts_start'] = isset($_SESSION['posts_start']) ? $_SESSION['posts_start'] : $number_of_posts; ?>;
//<?php $_SESSION['posts_start'] = $_SESSION['posts_start'] ? $_SESSION['posts_start'] : $number_of_posts; ?>;
//<?php $_SESSION['posts_start'] = 2 ?>;

//var start = <?php echo $_SESSION['posts_start']; ?>;

var start = {{ Session::get('posts_start', 2) }};
var initialPosts = <?php echo Fanartist::friend_activity_json(0, $_SESSION['posts_start']); ?>;
//var initialPosts = <?php echo Fanartist::friend_activity_json(0, 2); ?>;
var desiredPosts = <?php echo $number_of_posts; ?>;

var template = '<div class="item">'
        +'<img class="thumbnail pull-left" width="50px" height="50px" src="http://placehold.it/50x50" style="margin: 0px 10px 5px 0px;">'
        +'<a href="#"><h4 style="margin: 5px 0px;" class="first_name"></h4></a>'
        +'<p><small class="stage_name"></small></p>'
        +'<div class="well well-small created_at"></div>'
        +'</div>';

var widget = $('#widget'),
    // Element to load the posts
    content = widget.find('.content'),
    // the more button
    more = widget.find('.more'),
    // the post counter
    counter = widget.find('.badge');

// Create alerts elements (Display Success or Failure)
    var alerts = {
        requestEmpty : $('<div class="alert alert-info">No more data</div>'),
        requestFailure : $('<div class="alert alert-error">Could not get the data. Try again!</div>')
    }
    var progressElement = $('<div class="progress" style="margin-bottom:0"><div class="bar"></div></div>');
    var progressBar = progressElement.find('.bar');

    var postHandler = function(posts){

        // Set the progress bar to 100%
        progressBar.css('width', '100%');
        // Delay the normal more button to come back for a better effect
        window.setTimeout(function(){more.html('More <span class="caret"></span>')}, 500);

        // insert childrens at the end of the content element
        for (post in posts){
            // Clone the element
            var $post = $(template).clone();
            $post.attr('id', 'post-' + posts[post].ID);
            $post.find('.first_name').html(posts[post].first_name);
            $post.find('.last_name').html(posts[post].last_name);
            $post.find('.city').html(posts[post].city);
            $post.find('.gender').html(posts[post].gender);
            $post.find('.stage_name').html(posts[post].stage_name);
            $post.find('.created_at').html(posts[post].created_at);
            content.append($post);

        }

        content.animate({
            scrollTop: $('#post-' + posts[0].ID).offset().top + (content.scrollTop()- content.offset().top)
        }, 200);

    }

    // place the initial posts in the page
    postHandler(initialPosts);

    // add the click event to the more button
    more.click(function(){  
        // Set the progress bar to 0%
        progressBar.css('width', '0%');
        // remove the more button innerHTML and insert the progress bar
        more.empty().append(progressElement);
        // AJAX REQUEST
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://crowdtest.dev:8888/fans/setup_widget", 
            type: 'GET',
            // We do not want IE to cache the result
            cache: false,
            data: {  
                'start': start,  
                'desiredPosts': desiredPosts  
            }
        }).success(function (data, text) {
            // parse the response (typeof data == String)
            data = JSON.parse(data);
            if (data.length > 0){
                // Update the total number of items
                start += data.length;
                // Update the counter
                counter.html(start);
                // load items on the page
                postHandler(data);
            }else{
                $alert = alerts.requestEmpty;
                // insert the empty message
                widget.prepend($alert);
                // Set the progress bar to 100%
                progressBar.css('width', '100%');
                // Remove the more button
                window.setTimeout(function(){more.remove()}, 500);
                // remove the empty message after 4 seconds
                window.setTimeout(function(){$alert.remove()}, 4000);
            }
        }).error(function (request, status, error) {
            $alert = alerts.requestFailure;
            // insert the failure message
            widget.prepend($alert);
            // Set the progress bar to 100%
            progressBar.css('width', '100%');
            // Delay the normal more button to come back for a better effect
            window.setTimeout(function(){more.html('More <span class="caret"></span>')}, 500);
        });

    });

console.log(desiredPosts);
console.log(start);
console.log(initialPosts);

});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="widget">
    <h4 id="widget-title">
        Widget Title <span class="badge badge-info"><?php echo $_SESSION['posts_start'] ?></span>
    </h4>
    <div class="content" style="height: 300px; overflow: auto; margin: 0px;"></div>
    <button class="more btn btn-block">
        More <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

I would like to have this functionality outside of the widget, displayed in a table.  For a specific row, I want the data:

```
<tr>
                                <td><div class="friend_image"><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/{{ $fbid }}/picture" alt="{{$first_name}}" height="65" width="65" class="img-rounded"></div></td>
                                <td><div class="friend_activity"><span class="activity_text">{{$first_name}} {{$last_name}} indicated that @if($gender=='male') he @else she @endif wants <a href="/artists/{{$artist_id}}">{{$stage_name}}</a> to come to {{$city}}</span>
                                    <br><span class="activity_subtext">{{StringEdit::getDate($created_at)}}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
```

Do you know how I would do this?  Thank you for your help and suggestions.

Comment: still a valid question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your javascript or replace the old `var template`:

```
var trTemplate = '<tr class="post"><td><div class="friend_image">'
    + '<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/{{$fbid}}/picture" height="65" width="65" class="img-rounded">'
    + '</div></td><td><div class="friend_activity">'
    + '<span class="activity_text">{{$first_name}} {{$last_name}} indicated that {{$pronoun}} wants <a href="/artists/{{$artist_id}}">{{$stage_name}}</a> to come to {{$city}}</span>'
    + '<br><span class="activity_subtext"></span></div></td></tr>';
```

and add this to the `postHandler` method or replace the old `for (post in posts)` part

```
for (post in posts) {
    var $trPost = $(trTemplate).clone();
    $trPost.attr('id', 'trPost-' + posts[post].ID);

    var $img = $trPost.find('div.friend_image').find('img');
    $img.attr('src', $img.attr('src').replace('{{$fbid}}', posts[post].ID));
    $img.attr('alt', posts[post].first_name);

    var $spantext = $trPost.find('div.friend_activity').find('span.activity_text');
    $spantext.html($spantext.html().replace('{{$first_name}}', posts[post].first_name)
        .replace('{{$last_name}}', posts[post].last_name)
        .replace('{{$pronoun}}', posts[post].gender == 'male' ? 'he' : 'she')
        .replace('{{$artist_id}}', posts[post].artist_id)
        .replace('{{$stage_name}}', posts[post].stage_name)
        .replace('{{$city}}', posts[post].city));

    var $spansubtext = $trPost.find('div.friend_activity').find('span.activity_subtext');
    $spantext.html(posts[post].created_at);

    $('#tblPosts').append($trPost);
}
```

There are still some small details left (like the scrolling in the `postHandler` method) but you should be good to go from here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when I add that javascript portion with the new template, I get the error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined';  when I remove it, it doesn't give me that error.

Comment: 1) You need to add `<table id="tblPosts"></table>` to your html at the position where the table shall go. 2) Where exactly do you get the error (which part / line of the code)?

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` normally means that you are not loading jQuery before using it. You should load jquery.js as first script.

Comment: I do load it as first script.